# I want to test debug. I made Route in web.php file, give Request for parametre and i got error

Tags: php, laravel

web.php:

```
   function sum($a, $b) 
   {
      return $a + $b;
   }

Route::get('/debug/{$a}/{$b}', function(Request $request , $a, $b) {
     $sum = sum($a, $b);
     return $sum;
});
```

i get error in visual studio code 'Symbol $request declared but not used' and in my browser 404 not found, please help

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: 'Symbol $request declared but not used' in visual studio code and in browser 404 not found

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: So now what u get? show your url u r accessing

Comment: 404 not found in browser

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: What is the URL you are accessing? Do any other routes work? Are you getting the webserver 404 or the Laravel 404?

Comment: `Route::get('/debug/{a}/{b}'` without the `$` the `$` are only required for PHP variables not route parameters

Comment: 404 | not found

Comment: Your url should be a get method like `http://your-app-url/debug/1/3`

Comment: yes, it's  like this

Answer (score 0):

Just use below code :

```
Route::get('/debug/{a}/{b}', function($a, $b) {
      return sum($a , $b);
});
```

Or Simply use

```
Route::get('/debug/{a}/{b}', function($a, $b) {
      return ($a + $b);
   });
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters

Comment: this code you wrote is false,  when i wrote it  got me expected 2 arguments

Comment: sorry my mistake i added `+` instead of `,` updated my answer , try again

Comment: did u try it what u got?

Comment: @Leo please always response to the answer by upvoting and mark as green if it helps you